# Are there sideeffects in python using `if a == b == c: pass;`?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

```
if a == b == c:
    # do something
```

Let's assume `a, b, c` are string variables. Are there any possible side effects if I use the snippet above to execute `# do something` if and only if all three strings are equal?

I am asking because I have to check three variables against each other and I get many cases:

```
if a == b == c:
    # do something
elif a == b != c:
    # do something
elif a != b == c.
    # do something
etc...
```

Perhaps there is a better way to code this?

Comment: No, there aren't any side-effects.

Comment: The word *sideeffects* is misleading here. As a technical term, there obviously **can** be any possible sideeffects - if `a`, `b` or/and `c` are instances of classes, for which comparison operators are overridden in a way that causes sideeffects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There should be no side effects until you use it in a such way.

But take care about things like:

```
if (a == b) == c:
```

since it will break chaining and you will be comparing `True` or `False` and `c` value).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the parenthesis. I missed, that it would break the chaining!

Answer (score 16):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily; for example, x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

There should be no side effects.

Answer (score 6):

```
s = set([a, b, c])

if len(s) == 1:
    print 'All equal'
elif len(s) == 3:
    print 'All different'
else:
    l = list(s)
    print '%s and %s are different' % (l[0], l[1])
```

Answer (score -3):

is there any comment on x!=y!=z ?

i could use the stupid way to get a correct answer.

```
def aligndigits(list):

   return ((x, y , z ) for x in list for y in list for z in list if   x != y and y != z and x != z )
```